# Error al almacenar datos desde Python a SQL

Tags: python, mysql

Hola ya pude hacer funcionar un código que he bajado de github, tenia varios errores hasta que lo he corregido.

Ahora lo que sucede es que cuando me da los datos de los jugadores, al querer subirlo a la base de datos me sale el siguiente error **¡Error de almacenamiento! La instrucción SQL no se ejecuta normalmente**

Ese mensaje está en el siguiente código:

```
import pymysql

def insert(cur,table_name, values):
    #"""Insertar, los parámetros son el cursor, el nombre de la tabla y la cadena en los corchetes de valores, y devuelven la información de ejecución de la función"""
    if type(values) != str:
        return ("¡Error de parametro! los valores deben ser de tipo cadena")
    elif type(table_name) != str:
        return ("¡Error de parametro! table_name debe ser un tipo de cadena")
    else:
        sql_insert ="""insert into %s values(%s)"""
        try:
            cur.execute(sql_insert % (table_name, values))
            #eNVIAR
            cur.connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            #Error rollback
            cur.connection.rollback() 
            return ('¡Error de almacenamiento! La instrucción SQL no se ejecuta normalmente')
        else:
            return ('¡Almacenado con éxito!')
```

Y esto es lo que obtengo cuando ejecuto el comando  **pesdb.py**

```
C:\Users\Pao\Desktop\pesDB-master>py pesdb.py
Empezar PAGE： 1 Nombre del jugador y URL
¡Obtenido con éxito!
recuperando: L. MESSI Información
Procesando
¡Obtenido con éxito!
['Creative Playmaker']
 ['Double Touch', 'Long Range Drive', 'Chip Shot Control', 'Long Range Shooting', 'Dipping Shot', 'First-time Shot', 'One-touch Pass', 'Through Passing', 'Penalty Specialist', 'Captaincy']
 ['Trickster', 'Mazing Run', 'Speeding Bullet', 'Incisive Run', 'Early Cross']
Almacenar 1 Num de Jugador L. MESSI Información básica:
1,'./?id=7511','L. MESSI',10,'FC BARCELONA','Spanish League','ARGENTINA','South America',170,72,33,'Left foot','A','RWF',40,1,3,8,'Creative Playmaker','Double Touch','Long Range Drive','Chip Shot Control','Long Range Shooting','Dipping Shot','First-time Shot','One-touch Pass','Through Passing','Penalty Specialist','Captaincy',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Trickster','Mazing Run','Speeding Bullet','Incisive Run','Early Cross',NULL,NULL
¡Error de almacenamiento! La instrucción SQL no se ejecuta normalmente
```

Alguna solución para poder almacenar esos datos desde python a MySQL o SQLServer?
Tendría que usar otra librería?
Estoy usando la librería **pymysql**, desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Dejo código de pesdb.py

```
import pymysql  #导入 pymysql
import DBOperation as db_o
import GetInfo as gi
 
#设置要获取的页面号
page_num = 1
 
data_name = ['Capacidad ofensiva']
players_urlid, players_name, players_num, level_datas, other_info = [], [], [], {}, []
playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles = [], [], []
#打开数据库连接
db= pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="jkdev",
            password="Asd@02322!",db="pesdb",port=3306)
cur = db.cursor()
 
gi.getpageinfo(page_num, players_urlid, players_name)
players_num = [((page_num-1) * len(players_urlid) + i + 1) for i in range(len(players_urlid))]
 
for i in range(len(players_urlid)):
    gi.getplayerinfo(players_urlid[i][2:], players_name[i], data_name, level_datas, other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
    
    print(playing_style,'\n',player_skills,'\n',com_playing_styles)
    
    db_o.insert_baseinfo(cur, players_num[i], players_urlid[i], players_name[i], other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
    #for table_name, leval_data in level_datas.items():
    #db_o.insert_abilitys(cur,   , players_num[i], players_name[i], leval_data)
    print('--------------------------------------')
    
#关闭数据库和光标
cur.close()
db.close()
```

Archivo DBOperation.py

```
import MySQL
def insert_baseinfo(cur, player_num, player_urlid, player_name, other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles):
    """向数据库中插入球员的基本信息"""
    print('Almacenar', player_num, 'Num de Jugador', player_name,'Información básica:')
    if type(player_num) != int:
        print('¡Error de parametro! El número de jugador debe ser de plástico.')
    elif type(player_urlid) !=str:
        print('¡Error de parametro! La URL del jugador debe ser un tipo de cadena')
    elif type(player_name) !=str:
        print('¡Error de parametro! El nombre del jugador debe ser un tipo de cadena')
    elif type(other_info) != list:
        print('¡Error de parametro! Otra información debe ser una lista')
    else:
        base_info_head = "%d,'%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,%s,%s,'%s','%s','%s',%s,%s,%s,%s"
        base_info_head = base_info_head % (player_num,player_urlid,player_name,other_info[0],
                                other_info[1],other_info[2],other_info[3],other_info[4],
                                other_info[5],other_info[6],other_info[7],other_info[8],
                                other_info[9],other_info[10],other_info[11],other_info[12],
                                other_info[13],other_info[14])
        playing_style_str = ['NULL']
        player_skills_str = ['NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL']
        com_playing_styles_str = ['NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL']
        for i in range(len(playing_style)):
            playing_style_str[i] = "'" + playing_style[i] + "'"
        for i in range(len(player_skills)):
            player_skills_str[i] = "'" + player_skills[i] + "'"
        for i in range(len(com_playing_styles)):
            com_playing_styles_str[i] = "'" + com_playing_styles[i] + "'"
        base_info_last = ",%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" 
        base_info_last = base_info_last % (playing_style_str[0],player_skills_str[0],player_skills_str[1],
            player_skills_str[2],player_skills_str[3],player_skills_str[4],player_skills_str[5],player_skills_str[6],
            player_skills_str[7],player_skills_str[8],player_skills_str[9],player_skills_str[10],player_skills_str[11],
            player_skills_str[12],player_skills_str[13],player_skills_str[14],com_playing_styles_str[0],
            com_playing_styles_str[1],com_playing_styles_str[2],com_playing_styles_str[3],
            com_playing_styles_str[4],com_playing_styles_str[5],com_playing_styles_str[6])
        base_info = base_info_head + base_info_last
        print(base_info)
        print(MySQL.insert(cur, 'players', base_info))

def insert_abilitys(cur, table_name, player_num, player_name, leval_data):
    """向数据库中插入球员的各项能力1-60级数据"""
    print('Almacenar', player_num, 'Jugador de números', player_name,'Información de habilidades:')
    if type(player_num) != int:
        print('¡Error de parametro! El número de jugador debe ser de plástico.')
    elif type(player_name) !=str:
        print('¡Error de parametro! El nombre del jugador debe ser un tipo de cadena')
    elif type(leval_data) != str:
        print('¡Error de parametro! Los datos de calificación deben ser de tipo cadena')
    else:
        values = "%d,%s" % (player_num, leval_data)
        print(MySQL.insert(cur, table_name, values))
```

Código GetInfo.py

```
"""从HTML网页上获取信息"""
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def getpageinfo(page_num, players_urlid, players_name):
    """获得页面中球员的姓名及urlid"""
    print("Empezar PAGE：", page_num, "Nombre del jugador y URL")
    if page_num==1:
        html = urlopen('http://pesdb.net/pes2021/')
    else:
        html = urlopen('http://pesdb.net/pes2021/?page=' + str(page_num))
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for row in bsObj.table.find_all('a',{"href":re.compile("\.?id=.*")}):
        players_urlid.append(row.attrs['href'])
        players_name.append(row.get_text())
    print("¡Obtenido con éxito!")
    
def get_abilities(bsObj, data_name, level_datas):
    abilities = bsObj.find('script',text=re.compile('abilities.*')).get_text()
    abilities = abilities[1:-3].replace(',[','').split("]")
    for i in range(len(data_name)):
        level_datas[data_name[i]] = abilities[i]
    
def get_styles(bsObj, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles):
    #获取风格信息
    table = bsObj.find('th',text = 'Playing Style').parent.parent.find_all('tr')
    styles = []
    for i in range(len(table)):
        styles.append(table[i].get_text())
    #获取索引
    playing_style_index = styles.index('Playing Style')
    player_skills_index = styles.index('Player Skills')
    com_playing_styles_index = styles.index('COM Playing Styles')
    #将风格信息切片
    playing_style_label = styles[playing_style_index + 1:player_skills_index]
    for i in playing_style_label:
        playing_style.append(i)
    player_skills_label = styles[player_skills_index + 1:com_playing_styles_index]
    for i in player_skills_label:
        player_skills.append(i)
    com_playing_styles_label = styles[com_playing_styles_index + 1:]
    for i in com_playing_styles_label:
        com_playing_styles.append(i)
        
def get_oterinfo(bsObj, other_info):    
    #获取其他基本信息
    tds = bsObj.table.tr.td.table.find_all('td')
    other_info1 = []
    for i in range(len(tds)):
        other_info1.append(tds[i].get_text())
    other_info1 = other_info1[1:-2]
    if other_info1[0] == 'Free Agents':
        other_info1 = ['NULL']+other_info1
    tds = bsObj.table.tr.td.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.table.find_all('td')
    other_info2 = []
    for i in range(len(tds)):
        other_info2.append(tds[i].get_text())
    other_info2 = other_info2[8:-3]
    other_info_label = other_info1 + other_info2
    for i in other_info_label:
        other_info.append(i)
        
def getplayerinfo(player_urlid, player_name, data_name, level_datas, other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles):
    """根据球员id获得球员信息"""
    print('recuperando:',player_name,'Información')
    html = urlopen('http://pesdb.net/pes2021/' + player_urlid)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    print('Procesando')
    del other_info[:], playing_style[:], player_skills[:], com_playing_styles[:]
    #获取能力值
    get_abilities(bsObj, data_name, level_datas)
    
    #获取风格信息
    get_styles(bsObj, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
    
    #获取其他基本信息
    get_oterinfo(bsObj, other_info)
    print('¡Obtenido con éxito!')
```

Comment: Parece que tu consulta sql está dando un error. Como salta dicho error va al except y muestra ese mensaje. Prueba con ejecutar esta linea de la función insert `cur.execute(sql_insert % (table_name, values))` fuera del bloque try except. Si haces eso debería de mostrarte un error comun de Python. Podrías agregar ese error a la pregunta por favor (en forma de texto)?

Comment: Otra cosa, si no es muy largo, podrías agregar en la pregunta el código de tu archivo pesdb.py?

Comment: Gracias por tu respusta @DanteS. y si me arrojo varios erroes. Lamentablemente el código de pesdb.py es bastante extenso. Y este es el error que me arrojo al inicio

`pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")`

Comment: Te dejo el enlace en pastebin del código para que lo puedas ver 

[Código](https://pastebin.com/gTULrnpH)

Comment: Dos cositas. Primero podrías editar la pregunta (el boton editar está abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas) y agregar el mensaje allí por favor? Segundo, entonces podrías poner en la pregunta la parte del código donde llamas a la función insert y falla?

Comment: No es tan estenso como pensaba, agregalo en la pregunta, no pasa nada c:

Comment: No llamas a la función insert en ninguna parte del código que pasaste por pastebin. Habrá una función a mitad de camino entre tu código y la función insert? Es decir por ejemplo llamas a insertar_dato e insertar dato llama a la funcion insert?

Comment: Listo, ya he pasado los dos códigos que se llaman, en realidad son 4 archivos.

Comment: DBOperation.py, pesdb.py, MySQL.py y GetInfo.py

Comment: Genial! Gracias por todos los detalles! Quizá la consulta se está generando mal. Antes de ejecutar la consulta en la función insert agrega la linea `print(sql_insert % (table_name, values))` y cuentame cual es la ultima cosa que te muestra antes del error.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124541/discussion-between-dante-s-and-joaqho-c).

Comment: Te deje mensjaes en el chat, gracias por tu ayuda!